# Action issue preventing domain from being generated

Tags: skyve

Hi all getting the following error when generating the domain:

Action privilege NextStep for customer skyve in module tABSPOC for document TenementNote for role Viewer does not reference a valid action.

I have defined the following action in the view (edit.xml)

```
<actions>
        <defaults/>
        <action displayName="NextStep" className="NextStep" inActionPanel="true" />
</actions>
```

Did I miss a step or have I incorrectly defined the action?

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- check that you have a class in the *TenementNote.actions* package called *NextStep* and declared as follows:

```
public class NextStep implements ServerSideAction<TenementNote>
```

(if the package does not exist, create it by right-clicking on the TenementNote package and choose New->Package in eclipse)

- check that you have declared permissions in the module xml file for TenementNote like this

```
<document name="TenementNote" permission="#####">
    <action name="NextStep"/>
</document>
```

If that is all in place, refresh your project and try again.

Also if using eclipse, a default run config will be created for your project -  - New Action, this will prompt you in the console for module name, document name and action name and create the package for you.
If you are not using eclipse, you can still trigger this via maven using *mvn skyve:newAction* . I believe this is documented in the readme in the root directory of new projects.